# Custom strategy for warden not getting called

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, warden

I am trying to use a different warden strategy to authenticate my action cable end points.
But the strategy is not getting called. I tried to place `warden.authenticate!(:action_cable_auth)` in a controller to test but none of the debug statements are getting printed on console.

Below are the relevant part of the code.

```
config/initializers/warden.rb
Warden::Strategies.add(:action_cable_auth)  do
  def valid?
    #check if its a websocket request & for action cable?
    #Rails.logger.error request.inspect
    p 'checking if strategy is valid?'
    true
  end

  def authenticate!
    p 'unauthenticate the user'
    fail!('user not active')
  end
end
```

in my controller

```
 warden.authenticate!(:action_cable_auth)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are setting your initializer in the proper place, please recall that if your session is already instantiated somewhere else (for example if you `authenticate` the user at the point your action is being called, then your strategy will never be called.

This is basically how `warden` works: if some `valid?` strategy returns a `success!` then no other will be called as soon as any `authenticate!` method in the list of strategies is successful.

Please also be sure that if you want your strategy up the list of strategies to check you may need to also shift it up on the list, such as:

```
manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift(:action_cable_auth)
```

Where the `manager` is your `Warden::Manager` instance. The `scope` may also be optional (this is an example where the user scope is used alongside Devise), but you may check your instance `.default_strategies` to figure out where it is and where you want it.